# How to ensure a certain methods gets called in abstract super-class from method in sub-class (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract super class A with a method `doSomething()`. A sub-class of `A` must implement `doSomething()`, but there is also some common code that should be called every time a subclass calls `doSomething()`. I know this could be achieved thus:

```
public class A {
  public void doSomething() {
    // Things that every sub-class should do 
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public void doSomething() {
    super.doSomething();
    // Doing class-B-specific stuff here
    ...
  }
}
```

There seem to be three issues with this, though:

- The method signatures have to match, but I might want to return something in the sub-class methods only, but not in the super-class
- If I make A.doSomething() abstract, I can't provide a (common) implementation in A. If I don't make it abstract, I can't force sub-class to implement it.
- If I use a different method to provide the common functionality, I can't enforce that B.doSomething() calls that common method.

Any ideas how the methods should be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add call back to doSomething()

```
public class A {
  public void doSomething() {
    // Things that every sub-class should do 
    doSomethingMore()
  }
}

protected abstract void doSomethingMore()
```

so all subclusses will have to ipmelment doSomethingMore() with additional actions but external classes will call public doSomething()

Comment: I would add `final` to `public void doSomething()`. That should guarantee that it can't be overridden by a sub-class (which the Naive Coder (me in 2 months) might do).

Answer (score 6):

What about the following?

```
public abstract class A {
  protected abstract void __doSomething();

  public void doSomething() {
    // Things that every sub-class should do 
    __doSomething();
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  protected void __doSomething() {
    // Doing class-B-specific stuff here
    ...
  }
}
```

The first bullet point however is not so clear. The signature can't match if you want to return something different.

Comment: OP wants to return something, so you can change `__doSomething()` return type to may be generic type `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this way (same as Kachanov's) works for my purpose. Sorry for being unclear about the thing with the return value, but using the callback mechanism solves the return value problem.

Answer (score 0):

For first point alone - you can consider the below answer and for enforcing subclass implementation it can be abstract but calling common code functionality can happen if the base class has some implementation.

Return type can be Object in Base Class and returning null. In SubClass the specific return type can be put as given below.

```
public class InheritanceTutorial {

    static class Base{
        public Object doSomething(){
            System.out.println("parent dosomething");
            return null;
        }
    }

    static class SubClass extends Base{
        public Integer doSomething(){
            super.doSomething();
            System.out.println("child dosomething");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        subClass.doSomething();
    }

}
```